# Arduino scrolling text program freeze after some time

Tags: c++, arduino, lcd

I use a 16x2 character LCD to display some text. What I want is first line is fixed and second line is scrolling.

I wrote a program which works fine but the problem is after some time Arduino does not respond. I suspect there might be a bug or memory leak in the code.

The relevant code is like this.

```
void scrollTextFromRight(int line, char text[])
{
    const char space[16] = "                ";
    char screen[16];
    char * longText;

    longText = malloc(sizeof(char) * (sizeof(text) + 17));

    memset(longText, '\0', sizeof(char) * (sizeof(text) + 17));
    memset(screen, '\0', sizeof(screen));

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        longText[i] = space[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(text) + 17; ++j)
    {
        longText[16+j] = text[j];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(text) + 17; ++i)
    {

        lcd.setCursor(0, line);
        strncpy(screen, longText + i, 17 );
        lcd.print(screen);
        delay(350);
    }
}
```

I call this function from main program like this:

```
scrollTextFromRight(1, "Scrolling text");
```

**Update 1 :**
After reading the comments and answers I freed allocated memory space with free function. I uploaded the new code and testing whether it works as expected.

I added this part after the third for loop.

```
free longText;
```

**Update 2 :**
After reading the comments I decided to use Arduino's String class. The code became like this:

```
void scrollTextFromRight(int line, String text)
{
    const String space = "                ";
    const String longText = space + text + ' ';
    int displaySize = 16;

    for (int i = 0; i <= longText.length(); ++i)
    {
        lcd.setCursor(0, line);
        String display = longText.substring(i, i + displaySize);
        lcd.print(display);
        delay(350);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be because you never free the memory pointed by `longText`?

Comment: `sizeof(text)` does not do what you think. You (probably) won't allocate enough memory, and so get *undefined behaviour* writing beyond its bounds.

Comment: Also `sizeof(text)` is not the length of the string pointed by text, use `strlen(text)` instead. Same problem with `sizeof(screen)`

Comment: Also your use of the "magic numers" (google that) `16`, and `17` is questionable, use constants instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the argument as `char text[]`, the compiler translates it as `char* text`. That is, it's a pointer.

And getting the size of a pointer (e.g. `sizeof(text)`) gives you the size of the *pointer* and not whatever it points to. If it's a null-terminated byte string, then use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to get the length (but note that the null-terminator not counted).

Or even better, stop using C strings and functions, because Arduino is actually programmed in C++ and have its own standard [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class that should be used for all strings.

---

Also note that

```
const char space[16] = "                ";
```

creates an array of 16 elements, and set all those elements to the space character `' '`. ***But*** it's not a null-terminated string, because the terminator doesn't fit in the array.

You also know about the `memset` function, but seems to have forgotten the `memcpy` function when you copy from your arrays.

Instead of the explicit loop copying from `space`, you could simply do

```
memcpy(longText, space, sizeof space);  // Using sizeof since space is not null-terminated
```

Lastly, be careful with the [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) function, it might not null-terminate the destination string.